# xmlhttp.responseText after second ajax request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, ajax-request

i m writing a script using javascript ajax request and php..
i make an ajax call to verify that a user is recognised or not and according to the "response" i want to make a second ajax request either letting him either make his choices if his is already a registered user, or display the already submitted choices

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        removeOnclick();
        //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","submit_votes.php?q="+str+string,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

on my php side

i have these lines in case he is recognised

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "document.getElementById('".$row['option1']."').className += ' colour1';";
    ....
}
```

but if he is not recognised i have set this check

```
if (!isset($_GET['option1'])){ //option1 is one of the parameters i pass through "string"
    echo "nodata";
    }
```

the first call is made passing only the string is set ""

```
 q="+str+string
```

while on the second call string is set as option1=A&option2=B etc etc...

the issue is, that i try to alert the xmlhttpresponse to check if the response has been altered, but the resposne remains the same..for instance if he is not recognised i ll get in both responses "nodata" while if i refresh the page and he is recognised, i ll get the document.getElementById('".$row['option1']."').className += ' colour1'; response..

the reason i need this is because i want this part

```
    var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        removeOnclick();
        //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=
```

to be executed only if he is recognised..

Comment: This approach seems overcomplicated, besides being really clunky [echoing js code via php? why?]. Just put your resources behind an authorisation firewall [even basic HTTP Auth as a start], then make your choices based on the response code: you will find [this read](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/security.html) useful, and [this one](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife) as well.

Comment: i echo js through php, because i want according to the output of the db that i m running a query, to perform some changes on the styling of user's choices..but that part of code was out of scope so i didn't include it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after considering moonwave99 's comment as well, i ended up with a different solution..

first of all i found out, that condition check failed, because in the responseText there was an extra white space..so initially i used

```
xmlhttp.responseText.trim();
```

in order to remove unwanted characters...but it still didn't feel right the fact that i was passing js code as string from php back to js.. and i decided to use json..
so on the php side, i used json encode

```
$options = array($row['option1'],$row['option2'],$row['option3'],$row['option4'],$row['option5'],$row['option6'],
                    $row['option7'],
                    $row['option8'],
                    $row['option9'],
                    $row['option10']
                    );
echo json_encode($options);
```

and on the javascript side i used

```
    var jsObject = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var jslength = jsObject.length;
    for (i=0; i<jslength; i++){
        document.getElementById(jsObject[i]).className += ' colour';
    }
```